# Cut transparent background using Python(pillow)

Tags: python, html, image, discord, python-imaging-library

I used the python module html2image to convert html to an image, but due to the fixed image size, the html is broken or cut off and there is a blank space. Is there any way to solve this problem using Python? (I use chat exporter to generate html code)

```py
@commands.command("savemsg")
    async def savemsg(self, ctx, msgid, *, add_css=None):
        msglist = await ctx.channel.fetch_message(msgid)
        transcript = await chat_exporter.raw_export(ctx.channel, [msglist], "Asia/Seoul")

        if transcript is None:
            return

        f = open("savemsg.html", 'wb')
        f.write(transcript.encode())
        f.close()
        with open('savemsg.html') as f:
            hti.screenshot(html_str=f.read(), save_as='output.png', css_str=add_css)
        await ctx.send(content="Output", file=discord.File("output.png"))
```

Return https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/833899986805719040/846029096584216626/outr.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to crop the non-transparent area using Python:

- Read the input image, and convert it to NumPy array.
  The array has 4 color channels, the 4'th channel is alpha (transparency channel).
- Find indices of non-transparent pixels - indices where alpha channel value is above zero.
- Get the minimum and maximum index in both axes (top left corner and bottom right corner).
- Crop the rectangle (and convert the cropped rectangle to an image).
- Save the cropped image (with RGBA color format).

---

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Read input image, and convert to NumPy array. 
img = np.array(Image.open('outr.png'))  # img is 1080 rows by 1920 cols and 4 color channels, the 4'th channel is alpha.

# Find indices of non-transparent pixels (indices where alpha channel value is above zero).
idx = np.where(img[:, :, 3] > 0)

# Get minimum and maximum index in both axes (top left corner and bottom right corner)
x0, y0, x1, y1 = idx[1].min(), idx[0].min(), idx[1].max(), idx[0].max()

# Crop rectangle and convert to Image
out = Image.fromarray(img[y0:y1+1, x0:x1+1, :])

# Save the result (RGBA color format).
out.save('inner.png')
```

---

Result:
[image]

---

Sorry for ignoring the HTML tag...
I hope you really meant to ask "How to cut the area with the non-transparent background using Python" (and you are not looking to solve it using html2image
module).